# GIMP smooth brush doesn't draw smooth

Tags: gimp

I'm trying to paint a smooth dot with the 50% smooth brush.

However, GIMP draws it sharp instead of smooth.

What am I doing wrong here?

"View->Snap to Grid" is turned off.

Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you are using the "Pencil" and not the "Brush". The "Pencil" doesn't do soft edges (this is its main (only?) difference with the brush).